# TypeError: $ionicHistory.removeBackView is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to remove previous state from history so that clicking back will take user two states back. Here is what I did.

```
app.controller('postBlogCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http, $ionicLoading, 
                        $rootScope, $filter, genericServices, $ionicHistory){

    if($rootScope.previousStateName != "app.community-feed"){
        $ionicHistory.removeBackView();
    }
};
```

I am getting an error `TypeError: $ionicHistory.removeBackView is not a function`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems  like your version of ionic is  too old .
Use "ionic info" into the CLI to check your version . 
I know for sure that this removeBackView() is not present in ionic 1.2.4 but present in 1.2.7

.Alternatively you can check www/lib/ionic/js/ionicbundle.js  . If this file contains the removeBackView() method then something else seems to be the problem . If not , just upgrade the ionic version . You can visit  http://code.ionicframework.com/  to check the ionicbundle.js of different versions .Choose a version  whose ionicbundle.js file has this function

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem where removeBackView() didn't work. So instead I added this in the previous state leading to the state that I want to remove the back-button from:

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions( {
    disableBack : true
} );
```

Comment: I didn't want to remove back button. Instead I wanted to go back two states.